# Huge number of package changes when using conda to upgrade from tensorflow 1.14.0 to 2.2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to update tensorflow within one of my conda environments. But, each time I get set to update, the preview shows far more packages being upgraded/added/removed than I believe is anywhere near reasonable. I want to figure out whether I have a faulty understanding of:

- Package interdependency, so should just let everything proceed, because it is fine.
- What I'm doing, so need to proceed cautiously in order to understand how I'm changing my environment.

When I examine my current environment (i.e. `dnn_py3`), I see:

```
(dnn_py3) me@Home:~$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/me/anaconda3/envs/dnn_py3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
...
tensorboard               1.14.0           py37hf484d3e_0    anaconda
tensorflow                1.14.0          gpu_py37h4491b45_0    anaconda
tensorflow-base           1.14.0          gpu_py37h8d69cac_0    anaconda
tensorflow-estimator      1.14.0                     py_0    anaconda
tensorflow-gpu            1.14.0               h0d30ee6_0    anaconda
```

I want to upgrade to tensorflow 2.2.0

When I enter

```
(dnn_py3) me@Home:~$ conda update tensorflow-gpu
```

or

```
(dnn_py3) me@Home:~$ conda update -n dnn_py3 tensorflow-gpu
```

I get an extremely excessive (I think) list of downloads, new installs, removals, superceded packages and downloads, which I've summarized here:

```
Summary of Changes:
122 - download packages
5 - installs (none actually tensorflow !?)
24 - removals
263 - upgrades
140 - updates
```

I currently use tensorflow 1.14 in my environment, so I don't understand why this upgrade requires so much to be done. I expected to see only 1 upgrade (for tensorflow-gpu) and, possibly, a small number of other changes - nothing like the avalanche of proposed changes that I do see.

Since what I see differs so greatly from what I expect, I'd like to understand what's going on, before proceeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple reasons why this might be occurring.

### 1: Dependency Updates

Conda has a two-stage solving strategy. First, it attempts to satisfy the user specification by only installing/updating the specified packages. If this is possible without any other changes, then it considers the solve complete and will propose these (minimal) changes. Otherwise, it will move on to the second stage of solving, which allows all dependencies that need to be changed to be updated. This is recursively true, i.e., dependencies of dependencies may also update. Hence, this could lead to many updates.

Additionally, there is a configuration option, [**update_dependencies**](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#disable-updating-of-dependencies-update-dependencies), to allow *all* packages in a dependency chain to update, not just the ones that conflict with the user specification. The default for this option is `False`, but it may be worth checking that it is off (`conda config —-show update_dependencies`).

### 2: Changes in Channel Configuration

Many users eventually require a package from non-default channels, Conda Forge being the most common. Since [Conda Forge recommends prioritizing the **conda-forge** channel](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/introduction.html#how-can-i-install-packages-from-conda-forge), this often leads users to alter their global channel configuration. Whenever a user makes such a change, it effectively changes the context in which all future solving occurs. In particular, whenever a package is subject to changing it will try to switch to a build from the higher priority channel.

OP only shows builds from **anaconda** channel in the original environment, so a change in channel priorities is a definite possibility. However, without seeing the actual proposed changes, I can’t say for sure this is the driving cause.

### 3: Auto-Updates

The `conda` package and the `aggressive_updates_packages` will attempt update whenever a mutating operation is requested for an environment. So, these could show up as unrequested installations. However, this likely not relevant to OP, since such packages mainly pertain to the **base** environment, but OP clearly shows this is issue is not with **base**. Nevertheless, I enumerate it here mostly for completeness, since it could be the issue for other users.

Answer (score 0):

I would use conda to install tensorflow. It will install tensorflow 2.1.0. Tensorflow 2 works with or without a gpu. It also installs cuda toolkit 10.1.243 and cudnn 7.6.5. Conda can only install tensorflow up to version 2.1.0. After you install version 2.1.0 you can install version 2 using pip. Version 2 of tensorflow is compatible with the toolkit version 10.1.243 and cudnn 7.6.5 which conda already installed.